# How does operator.itemgetter() work in this code?

Tags: python

```
csv1 = csv.reader(scoreboard, delimiter=",")
sort = sorted(csv1, key=operator.itemgetter(0), reverse = True) 

for x in sort[:6]:
    print(x)
```

I am hoping someone can explain to me what's happening in the above code.

Comment: Which part of the code is unclear? Did you consult the relevant documentation?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" is stated in the what topics can I ask about. This is a problem unique to software development and is practical. They did not define what a practical problem is, therefore it is up to interpretation. This question fits with my interpretation of the above statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On first line you're oreading a comma separated file (.csv). It will probably be a table or something similar.

On the second line you're sorting it based on the first element in descending order (biggest values first). That means that you are sorting the table considering the first column.

On the for loop you print the first 6 elements of the sorted array